# Conección de Oracle database 12c con Power BI

Tags: oracle, powerbi

He intentado conectarme a una base de datos de Oracle 12c instalada en una maquina virtual en windows 7 por medio del programa Power BI, sin embargo me arroja el error Details: "Oracle: ORA-12545: La conexión ha fallado porque el host destino o el objeto no existen

instale el cliente de oracle y modifique el archivo TNSNAMES de la siguiente manera

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = FIDE)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

LISTENER_FIDE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.2.15)(PORT = 1521))


FIDE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.2.15)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = FIDE)
    )
  )
```

Sin embargo sigo teniendo el mismo error al conectarme

Comment: Si estás intentando conectarte desde Power BI Desktop, valida que el cliente Oracle tenga la misma arquitectura que el Power BI Desktop instalado; es decir, si tu Power BI Desktop es de 32 bits, que el cliente Oracle sea de 32 bits, e igual para si Power BI Desktop es de 64 bits. Recomiendo validar si, con alguna herramienta nativa del mismo Oracle puedes conectarte a la BD Oracle. Ya desde Power BI Desktop solo queda conectarte con el nombre de tu SID, en este caso, FIDE y, dado el caso, proveer credenciales de acceso.

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda, al final fue un error en la configuración del TNS y los datos utilizados para conectarse con Power BI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se genero al tener una configuración distinta en el TNS y los datos que se estaban utilizando para conectarse con Power BI.